# can I create output, depending on the key of dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

I have dictionary that looks like this: `'a': 'NPRO,206', 'b': 'PREP,131', 'c': 'PRCL,120', 'd': 'NPRO,66'`etc.
I want to create output that will look like this:`NPRO:'a,d', PRCL:'c', PREP:'b'`

Comment: You should show what code you have attempted.

Comment: I'd reformat your data structure so that it was a Pandas dataframe with two columns and rownames of `a`, `b`, etc.  The first column would be `['NPRO', 'PREP', ...]` and the 2nd `[206, 131, ...]`

Comment: @rnso code for doing what?

Comment: Code for producing output that you need.

Comment: that's the point of the question, I don't know what can I try. I want to take key of the item and put the key in front of the item, change their places. It doesn't matter what kind of output variable it will be tho, either string, array or smth else.

Comment: @4lll0w_3v1l there are many `reputation hunters` here that will answer your question. But **always try to code something SOMETHING**, doesn't matter you solve the problem or not always give it a try before asking for help. If you want to solve such problem by yourself one day don't rely on other... See while I am typing a "reputation hunter" gave the answer, well now answer is there i will try to give a more generic answer

Comment: @ZainArshad well said.

Comment: @ZainArshad I mean, you are right, but I was trying to code, was trying to find answers and couldn't find anything, that's why it's my first question, I just couldn't think of something or find some similar topics, that would help me in solving this problem

Comment: @ZainArshad Sorry, I'm new here, I don't know why'd I hunt for reputation - I don't even know what it does. Just trying to be helpful.

Comment: @4lll0w_3v1l  If you are a beginner, you have chosen a tricky question!

Comment: @dominik The idea behind the community is that we are not a code writting service for anyone that needs some code. We ll want to help everyone grow and learn. But we would at least like to see some attempt to solve the problem from the OP. Something that shows they have tried and that we can help them understand where they went wrong and how they can approach such problems in the future.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I get the sentiment, I just went under the assumption that OP has already tried some things and was still clueless. But yeah, I will keep this in mind from now on.

Comment: @ZainArshad So you just instantly went against your own principle and posted the full code instead of letting OP use my clue and think for themselves. Nice, mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to take all the values like `NPRO, PRCL`, note that they appear more than once. So, If you won't remove the duplicate ones you can end up adding same value to a key twice.

You can use `set()`, set is just like sets in mathematics. You can't have a duplicate value. Even if i put `1,2,3,3,1` in the set it finally it would look like `1,2,3`

Do something like this:

```py
d = {'a': 'NPRO,206', 'b': 'PREP,131', 'c': 'PRCL,120', 'd': 'NPRO,66'}
new_dict = {}
for k in set(val.split(',')[0] for val in d.values()):
    for key, value in d.items():
        if k in value:
            try:
                new_dict[k].append(key)
            except KeyError as err:
                new_dict[k] = [key]

print(new_dict)
```

This should print this:

```
{'NPRO': ['a', 'd'], 'PRCL': ['c'], 'PREP': ['b']}
```

**Note:**

This code can be improved but as you said you are new, I have kept things simple.

Comment: You can highlight that use of `set` avoids duplication of entries. Good idea.

Comment: You could also use a default dict with list so you can just do `new_dict[k].append(key)` without the need for the try and except

Comment: @ChrisDoyle now OP should improve the code himself, as I stated in the asnwer

Comment: Yeah i know, i am just adding more food for thought for the OP